# Tennis game with two different conventions for serving: show that the probability of win does not depend on the convention adopted.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

You are playing a match against an opponent in which at each point either you or your opponent serves. If you serve you win the point with probability $p_1$, but if your opponent serves you win the point with probability $p_2$. There are two possible conventions for serving:

(i) serves alternate;

(ii) the player serving continues to serve until she loses a point.

You serve first and the first player to reach n points wins the match. Show that your probability of winning the match does not depend on the serving convention adopted.

I guess I must find a relation between the alternate way of serving and the other way, showing that the probability of win is the same without necessarily calculate it, for example dividing the combinations of serving in the second way in different sets with the same resulting probability equal to that of the first way.

Edit: I finally solved the problem, for the solution see my answer.

Comment: Indeed, it looks so. For n=2, the probability in both cases is $p_1(p_1+2p_2-2p_1p_2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by considering other rounds, after one player wins, until they are 2n-1 in total. In the first case (alternating convention) the services continue to alternate, while in the second we say that the loser will serve all the remaining rounds (after he had lost). The extended game is equivalent to the non extended: if you win one you win the other. So we consider the extended, which we have constructed in such a way that in both cases you have 2n-1 rounds, and in both cases you serve n rounds. So the probability that you win is the same in the two cases.